# How to store values in a text file into proper variables, as well as how to make this code block more legible?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a program that will allow the user to type which gaming console they have, and then type out each game they have for that console. I'm currently stuck on when the program loads all the previously saved information, having that information stored in the proper variables. I've made some progress, but I got stuck at a certain point, and would like some guidance on how to move forward.

```
    public static void FileReader() 
{
    try 
    {
        BufferedReader loadReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("GamesList.txt"));
        while((loadText = loadReader.readLine()) != null) // Search through each line
        {
            if(loadText.equalsIgnoreCase("Xbox One" ) || loadText.equalsIgnoreCase("Nintendo Switch") || loadText.equalsIgnoreCase("Playstation 4")) // Look for these consoles
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < consolesList.size(); x++) // Search through the entire arrayList of consoles
                {
                    if(consolesList.get(x).consoleName.equalsIgnoreCase(loadText)) // If the current consoles on value x matches the loadText
                    {
                        while((loadText = loadReader.readLine()) != null) // if there are still lines left to search
                        {
                            if(loadText.equalsIgnoreCase("Xbox One") && loadText != consolesList.get(x).consoleName) // I THINK this is needed to exit the first console, and start the second
                            {
                                System.out.println("This was run " + loadText); // Originally had a recursive call here, but that lead to a stack overflow. 
                            }
                            consolesList.get(x).gamesList.add(loadText); // Add all the games found back into the list of games
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("We didn't find anything " + loadText);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("This did nothing");
    }
}
```

Where I'm stuck is separating the consoles once all the current console's games have been listed. Let's say I add three games to the PlayStation 4, and then three games to the Xbox One. Once the program finds the text for the PlayStation, it will list all the games, but, it will also include the Xbox, and all of it's games, as the PlayStation's games. It will also never move on and actually search for Xbox One games, and list them as it's own. It simply stops there and continues the rest of the program. I know this happens on the line where the second while statement is, and I tried creating a recursive call there in order to get it to start over, but the same problem will happen again, since there is no actual increment, and just leads to a stack overflow. Any ideas on how I can get it to exit the first console, and start listing the second, and so on? Also, I'm guessing this code is difficult to read due to it being a bunch of nested if/for/while loops. Any advice on making it more legible?

-Solved- 
I was able to get it working by editing one line of Nayan Patel's code. I used a for loop to iterate through each element in the arrayList, and when each console was found, i set an index to that number, and added the games to that index.

```
    public static void FileReader() 
{
    try {
        BufferedReader loadReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("GamesList.txt"));
        //String loadText = "";
        int consoleIndex = -1; // for storing the console index
        while((loadText = loadReader.readLine()) != null) {
            // getting the index of loadText from consoleList.
            // store your consoles name in uppercase in consoleList.
            int index = -1;
            for(int x = 0; x < consolesList.size();x++) {
                if(loadText.equalsIgnoreCase(consolesList.get(x).consoleName)) {
                    index = x;
                }
            }
            if(index != -1){ // if console name is present in loadText
                consoleIndex = index;
                continue;
            }
            // put game in respected console.
            consolesList.get(consoleIndex).gamesList.add(loadText);
            System.out.println("We got to the end");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("This did nothing");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend a better file struct, such as JSON or XML

Comment: @MadProgrammer Even using a Properties file (one comma-delimited property for each console) would be an improvement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your question,

```java
try {
    BufferedReader loadReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("GamesList.txt"));
    String loadText = "";
    int consoleIndex = -1; // for storing the console index
    while((loadText = loadReader.readLine()) != null) {
        // getting the index of loadText from consoleList.
        // store your consoles name in uppercase in consoleList.
        int index = consolesList.indexOf(loadText.toUpperCase()); // 
        if(index != -1){ // if console name is present in loadText
            consoleIndex = index;
            continue;
        }
        // put game in respected console.
        consolesList.get(consoleIndex).gamesList.add(loadText);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("This did nothing");
}
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this, or anything else suggested, but I plan on trying them out first thing in the morning.